# Why do I get this error when installing Juypter?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip, jupyter

Hi I'm definitely not an advanced level user/coder.  I'm trying to learn Python (ver 3.12.2)

I'm trying to use Juypter to practice.

I'm on Windows 11, and when I try to install via CMD using pip, I get:

```
pip install juypter
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement juypter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for juypter
```

Pip version is 24.0

Is it worth trying to resolve it, or better to use some other tool?

Comment: The name of the package now is `notebook` I suspect jupyter doesn't work for newer pythons.

Comment: `pip install notebook` or `pip install jupyterlab`, depending on your taste. The [`jupyter` meta package](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter/) is indeed too old.

Comment: I've successfully installed juypterlab per the able.  I guess one of the problems with some YouTube content is it get stale pretty fast.  Thanks for your help!